# Javascript Sections

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website I want to take that always has the same section with the same id with all the content I want to display. I'm not very amazing at javascript and I'm wondering how I could remove everything but a specific section.

Would the best approach be to just do a loop that goes through all the elements in the DOM and remove everything but the section with the id I want to keep? If I go that approach how do I keep it from removing all the elements inside that section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps another way to do this more efficiently would be:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById( 'saveContentId' ).innerHTML
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the section, this might not be more efficient than usual DOM methods. Also don't forget the drawbacks of `innerHTML` like removed listeners

Comment: Yep, it probably can be done more efficiently. For my purposes though this one line of code does wonders.

Answer (score 1):

Removing one node includes all its children, so you won't need to loop over all elements in the whole document. I see two possibilities:

- get the section, remove all its siblings in the current parent, and then walk up the DOM tree until `document.body`, while removing all siblings.
- get the section and detach it from the document. Then clear `document.body` and re-attach the section there

The first solution seems cleaner to me, so here some sample code:

```
function removeEverythingBut(el) {
    while (el != document.body) {
        var par = el.parentNode;
        for (var i=par.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--)
             if (par.childNodes[i] != el)
                  par.removeChild(par.childNodes[i]);
        el = par;
    }
}

// usage:
removeEverythingBut(document.getElementById("my-section"));
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out though, let's see if it's any better!

Comment: There seems to be no difference between either solution for my purposes(taking a basic article and removing some unnecessary data). Thanks for the input anyways!

Answer (score 0):

you can save only the element you want and delete all other elements. Also I recommend using Jquery

Comment: for me Jquery is the easiest way to execute javascript.